# Create object of sets in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

```
arr1 = ['d1','d2','d3'];
```

using above data, i want to see the output like below.

```
[{n1 : 'd1', n2:'d1', n3 : 'd1'},
 {n1 : 'd2', n2:'d2', n3 : 'd2'}
 {n1 : 'd3', n2:'d3', n3 : 'd3'}
]
```

I tried following but the output is not as expected.

```js
arr1 = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'];

mapV =
  arr1.map((item, index, arr) => [{
    n1: 'd1',
    n2: 'd1',
    n3: 'd3'
  }]);

console.log(mapV);
```

o/p:

```
[   [ { n1: 'd1', n2: 'd1', n3: 'd3' } ],   [ { n1: 'd1', n2: 'd1', n3: 'd3' } ],   [ { n1: 'd1', n2: 'd1', n3: 'd3' } ] ]
```

Comment: You're never using `item` in the `map()` callback function. That should be an obvious problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can map-reduce each of the values:

```js
const expand = (arr) =>
  arr.map(x => Array.from({ length: 3 })
    .reduce((acc, _, i) => ({ ...acc, [`n${i + 1}`]: x }), {}));

console.log(expand(['d1','d2','d3']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

**Note:** In the code above `{ length: 3 }` is the size of the array. This can either be based on the size of the input, or set to something else.

Comment: How is this incorrect based on the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `item` in the callback function instead of hard-coding the same string each time.

You also have an extra level of array around each return value.

```js
arr1 = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'];

mapV =
  arr1.map((item) => ({
    n1: item,
    n2: item,
    n3: item
  }));

console.log(mapV);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the values along with the keys and build objects.

```js
const
    data = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'],
    keys = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'],
    result = data.map(v => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, v])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can i generated the keys dynamically ?

Comment: it depends, what you have and what you like to get. please add more information to the question.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you are implicitly returning an array, not an object. Try this:

```
mapV = 
    arr1.map((item,index,arr)=>
({n1 : 'd1', n2: 'd2', n3 : 'd3'})
);
```